# How to trigger button click event on pressing enter button in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I am creating a login form in windows phone app , I want to trigger login button event on pressing enter button from finishing the form.

**Requirement:** While clicking enter button from last text field in login page should trigger login button event..

**Code sample**
  I know how to move from one text field to another on clicking enter button as below

```
private void passkeydown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
 {
  nextfield .Focus();
  }
 }
```

But I don't know how to trigger button click event here.

Comment: can you try-> `LoginButton.PerformClick();`

Comment: check my below answer...

Comment: You are welcome :) glad tobe hep of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This:

```
if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
{
  LoginButton_Click(sender,e); //here LoginButton_Click is click eventhandler
}
```